# How can I split a vector python style in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector, say

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
```

I want to be able to extract parts of it, so that I can get the following cases, python style

```
a[1:0] gives c()
a[1:1] gives c()
a[1:2] gives c(1)
a[1:3] gives c(1,2)
```

Unfortunately this is not how splitting works in R:

```
a[1:0] gives c(1)
a[1:1] gives c(1)
a[1:2] gives c(1,2)
a[1:3] gives c(1,2,3)
```

The biggest problem for me is not to be able to get an empty c() when the index is at the start. Is there a workaround for this behavior? Otherwise I'll have to treat index 1 as a special case, something I'd prefer not to do.

Specifically, I have a set of chunks, and I want all the previous chunks and the next chunk:

```
  for (idx in seq_len(length(elems))) {
    prev_elems <- python_split(elems, 1, idx)
    cur_elem <- elems[[idx]]
```

prev_elems must be empty when idx is at the start, and all the already parsed elements afterwards. cur_elem must be the next element of the set.

Comment: `sapply(a - 1, function(x) a[seq_len(x)])` is almost there.

Comment: Although python and R are great languages and share alot, there is also much that the two differ upon. One is the indexing issue. R starts with 1 while python starts with 0. Python subsetting is made in such that `a[:2] + a[2:]` should be the whole list, Also since `a[:len(a)]` should work, hence the last index is excluded. On the other hand R includes it within. Unless you write your own class and define the behaviour of `:`, there is no way to replicate the Python behavoour in R. Just learn to take the way it is written after sometime you will appreciate it

Comment: @Onyambu I can't appreciate it if it's broken. I want to operate on a vector in chunks and I want the first chunk to be all left of a position, and the second to be all rights of a position. It's impossible in R to get the empty array, no matter what the indexes are.

Comment: *"Impossible"*? `(1:10)[seq_len(0)]` is empty, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Also note that there is no backward access in python. eg `a[2:1]` does not exist. it will always produce an empty list. On the other hand, in R, we just take the 2nd element then the first. Note that python uses Negative indices to reverse, R uses the same to exclude etc etc

Comment: No it is not _impossible_ but rather `a[0]` in R will always be the empty vector as @r2evans stated above. Obviously you can split/breakdown the vector the way you want. The issue here is since you are a _guru_ in python, and trying the pythonic subsetting in R, that wont work. Please Just take your time and know the basics of R. If at all you must use R, write everything in python, then translate using the `reticulate` package for those who will use R.

Comment: See modified answer for the actual issue

Comment: Stefano, R is certainly not a perfect language ... few (if any) are pedagogically pristine ... somebody somewhere will always be able to find some use-case that shows either design shortcomings or just a bad fit. There are many things about R that are frustrating, and even internally it can often be inconsistent with itself. If you think so lowly of it, though, might I suggest you stop using it and attempt to do what you need in another language that fits your standards?

Comment: @r2evans my job requires that I use it. If it were for me, I'd drop it today.

Comment: I don't the problem here is with R.

Comment: Although, we can all agree that with its flaws we can work around that. So in relation to your question, we can always find a solution as the one posted below by @r2evans. Great solution

Comment: Stefano - I'll just make this one comment then I digress... if I were programming imperative code in R, I'd think it were garbage too. R shines when you embrace its functionals.

Comment: @BillO'Brien I don't need its functionals. I need to be able to deliver a reliable, robust, consistent, validated solution that is debuggable, properly tested, properly communicative of intent, with chances of conflicts reduced to zero, and with a stable environment that is fully traceable throughout its dependency tree creation. R does not offer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
py_split <- function(x, a, b) x[a - 1 + seq_len(max(0, b-a))]
py_split(1:3, 1, 2)
# [1] 1
py_split(1:3, 1, 1)
# integer(0)
py_split(1:3, 1, 0)
# integer(0)
py_split(1:3, 1, 3)
# [1] 1 2
py_split(1:3, 2, 3)
# [1] 2
py_split(1:3, 2, 2)
# integer(0)
```